# How to run Nunit tests belongs to specific Namespace using ConsoleRunner

Tags: c#, unit-testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests, nunit

Is it possible to run NUnit tests that belong to a specific namespace in my .Net application? I tried to explore the commands that are available in NUnit online documentation and couldn't find commands to run tests in a namespace.

I have following structure in my application.

```
+AwesomeApp
+---AwesomeApp.WebApp
+---AwesomeApp.Services
+---AwesomeApp.WebApp.Tests
    +----AwesomeApp.WebApp.Tests.Unit
        +----UnitTest #1
        +----UnitTest #2
    +----AwesomeApp.WebApp.Tests.Integration
        +----IntegrationTest #1
        +----IntegrationTest #2
    +----AwesomeApp.WebApp.Tests.Regression
        +----RegressionTest #1
        +----RegressionTest #1
```

Note: each namespace within "AwesomeApp.WebApp.Tests" has many unit tests

I'm trying to figure out the commands to run all tests that are in **AwesomeApp.WebApp.Tests.Unit**, **AwesomeApp.WebApp.Tests.Integration** and **AwesomeApp.WebApp.Tests.Regression** separately. This is mainly because the **Unit tests** have to **run after every build**, **regression tests** have to **run once a month** and **Integration tests** are **manually triggered** by developers in their local system,

or is there a better way to achieve this? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **NUnit 3 console runner**, you use the `--where` command line option with the [Test Selection Language](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Selection-Language). For example,

```
nunit3-console.exe AwesomeApp.WebApp.Tests.dll --where "namespace == AwesomeApp.WebApp.Tests.Unit"
```

For developers running tests in **Visual Studio**, group your tests by namespace and run the namespaces,

[image]

[image]